An idea for making a 1 m long lens: collimating beams from a camera lens, transfering them over 1 m, then focusing them back to form an image
I am working on a project to build a custom lens that may need to extend to 1 m long.
I thought it would be costly to design one from scratch so I brought up some middle-school physics from the back of my mind and came up with this idea:

where:

Item 1 is an off-the-shelf M12 lens
Item 2-5 are plano-convex lenses
Item 6 is a camera with its lens removed.

If I place Item 2 at [focal distance of 1] + [focal distance of 2], I should get collimated beams. Lens 3 and 4 refocus the beams and then collimate them again, may not be necessary. I can then refocus the collimated beams at the focal length of 5 to form an image onto a CMOS.
So I bought some components and did an experiment.

For Item 1, I purchased a GJ-M12-25IR(5MP)-3 lens.
For Item 2-5, I purchased 15x60, uncoated plano-convex lens from Edmund
For Item 6, I used a Bluerobotics camera BR-100126 which has a 1/2.9 inch CMOS, with its lens removed.

The experiment setup:

The lens placements are certainly not 0.01 mm accurate but I did my best with a vernier caliper and some careful design with the 3D-printed lens holders. I covered the whole setup with the black Perspex cover and the blackout sheet on top. The resultant image is ... an image, but looks terrible.

Is this theory very flawed? Or would it improve the image if I use better optics, e.g. achromatic doublet? Or would I need a much more complex lens that is properly designed?
I also found, during the experiment:

placing the lens at the exact focal length calculation doesn't produce the best image, so I had to adjust the distances between lenses a little.
My eyes seem to see better images through the lens setup directly than using a CMOS, although at a much further distance from the last lens element, i.e. Item 5. I appreciate it if your answer could be extended a bit to include an explanation for this.


this is a proper question, well done

You might want to do a little research on periscope optics.

Well you've clearly got chromatic aberration, so achromatic lenses are a must. But since each lens contributes to your chromatic aberration, what does it look like without the extra lens set?

@EricS would you mind elaborating on periscope optics? My understanding of it is to use prisms to bend light by 90 degrees twice so you can see images above you, but there are also some complicated optics in between the prisms to transport light between the prisms. In my case, I don't need to bend the light, so I don't need prisms, but I need the optics between the prisms. The whole idea of this exercise is to avoid complicated optics to transport light. Are you suggesting I will need more complex optics than using these plano-convex lens?

@david I think it will be very good image if I install the M12 lens directly on the camera. I haven't been able to do so because I need to design and 3d print a lens holder.

@Anthony The folding mirrors or prisms aren't that important. Getting a good image to propagate down a long tube is where a periscope really does its work. By the way, there are many more optical experts on the photography stack exchange site than here. Also, if you are using plano-convex lenses, have the convex side face the collimated side.

Check out this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay_lens

@EricS thank you. Relay lens is the term I am searching for.
